# How to add a SELECT query inside a SUM() to show a total number of comments in a forum?

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have a small forum for an intranet website.
Each user can post N number of comments.
I want to show the top 10 users as the ten that commented the most.

I'm using MySQL.

### Here's what I've got:

```
|comment id | name      | userID |
|--------------------------------|
|142585     | pepe      | 24     |
|128635     | juan      | 20     |
|156582     | maria     | 5      |
|142585     | pepe      | 24     |
|142585     | pepe      | 24     |
|155682     | Andres    | 33     |
+--------------------------------+
```

### Here's my query:

(I'm using a join to get the user's names)

```
SELECT comm.commentID, comm.userID, user.name
FROM comm LEFT JOIN user
ON comm.userID = user.userID
ORDER BY comm.commentID DESC
```

Of course, this does not show me the sum. I've tried adding `GROUP BY comm.userID` but even if I group everything by the userID (so they are not duplicated), the only comment that appears is the latest comment id.

### This is what I want:

```
|Total      | name      | userID |
|--------------------------------|
|3          | pepe      | 24     |
|1          | juan      | 20     |
|1          | maria     | 5      |
|1          | Andres    | 33     |
+--------------------------------+
```

### This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT comm.commentID, comm.userID, user.name,
(SELECT SUM(comm.commentID) FROM comm WHERE user.userID = comm.userID) AS total
FROM comm LEFT JOIN user
ON comm.userID = user.userID
GROUP BY comm.userID
ORDER BY comm.commentID DESC
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT count(*) comm.userID, user.name,
FROM comm JOIN user
ON comm.userID = user.userID
GROUP BY comm.userID
```

your desired result doesn't have a comment ID , so why bother selecting it?

> even if I group everything by the userID (so they are not duplicated), the only comment that appears is the latest comment id.

well, sure.  if you want to concatenate them all together, `group_concat` can do it, but it has serious length limitations.